# Doing stops on Italian regional trains. How long exactly is the ticket valid?

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, italy, trenitalia

tl;dr: How long exactly are Italian regional train tickets valid if I interrupt my journey at intermediate stations?

I have an Italian regional train ticket and it says

> Vale 6 ore da convalida

i.e. valid for 6 hours from [validation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/69068/32134).

Q1: Does that mean I can take any train with a scheduled departure within those 6 hours or that I should take a train that (at least on schedule) arrives within those 6 hours?

Q2: Can I interrupt my train travel at an intermediate station (i.e. get off, walk around, take the next train) as long as both trains fulfill the requirement of Q1?

The typical example for this would be a tourist to the Cinque Terre, getting a ticket from La Spezia to Levante and interrupting his journey for an hour or two to see one of the villages of the Cinque Terre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must arrive within 6 hours. The ticket expires 6 hours after validation and if your ticket is checked on the train more than 6 hours from validation, you will be subject to a fine.

You may get on and get off multiple times and use the same ticket. The validity of the Cinque Terre train ticket is specifically designed to allow you to visit multiple or all towns on the one ticket.

http://www.leconchiglie-levanto.com/howto.php

> Tickets are good for 5, 10 and 20 kilometers, you have to validate
>   them at the yellow machines in the station before you start your
>   journey. They are valid for 6 hours. 10 km tickets are all you need
>   for the 5 villages.
>
> Tickets will be checked on the train! The trains run till about 11:30
>   pm And a single ticket exists which allows you to visit all of the
>   Cinque Terre.

http://www.hotelgrandealbergo.it/easynews/newsleggi.asp?newsid=105

> An alternative for those who decide not to walk and want only to move
>   by train would be to buy a round trip ticket Sestri Levante -
>   Riomaggiore at a cost of € 4.00 per person each way (always with the
>   regional trains), this ticket has a validity of 6 hours from the
>   validation time and you can stop  about 1 hour in every village. This
>   solution is certainly the most economically advantageous but it seems
>   that the Park intends to force all visitors to the [Cinque Terre Cards](http://www.cinqueterre.com/en/the-cinque-terre-card/),
>   in this case we will inform you in time!

Comment: Yup this. Exactly this.

Comment: Worth to note that the "Cinque Terre Cards" are for walking the trails of the park around the villages and as of now are not needed to enter the villages. They are different from the train tickets discussed here.

Comment: There is a Cinque Terre Card valid for trains too. http://www.cinqueterre.com/en/the-cinque-terre-card/#treno It sounds like the second link means that one

Comment: Given the cost of 4€ mentioned in the second link/quote I doubt they mean the Cinque Terre Card, but good to know it also includes trains.

Comment: I think the 4 euro is just a standard train ticket, but probably out of date. The hotel was trying to explain that the Park wants people to buy the more expensive Cinque Terre Card instead of just a train ticket